# Why vuetify checkbox reacts two times, on click in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i have a table, where every row contains a checkbox. When clicking on a checkbox i would like to call some logic (when someone clicks on a checkbox, sometimes i need to tick few rows, not only selected one, so i've made checkboxes readonly and i need to tick them in script section). Here's my table:

```
     <div
        v-for="file in files"
        :key="file.entry.name">
        <v-list-item style="height: 40px;">
          <v-list-item-content class="text-left">
            <div class="wrapper">
              <div class="checkbox">
                <v-checkbox
                  readonly
                  @click="selectCorrespondingFiles"
                  v-model="file.isSelected">
                </v-checkbox>
              </div>
              <div class="title">
                <v-list-item-title
                  style="font-size: 16px"
                  v-text="file.entry.name">
                </v-list-item-title>
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
      </div>
```

When i click on a checkbox my method is called two times:

```
    selectCorrespondingFiles() {
      console.log('selectCorrespondingFiles');
      ....
    },
```

Why the code is being executed two times on every click? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try,   `@click.stop="selectCorrespondingFiles"`

This will stop next calls and will call one function at a time.